# how to directly manipulate an already formed date string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

am using react date picker to allow user to select "from date" and "to date"

"2023-03-13T15:30:42.000Z"  "2023-03-14T15:30:42.000Z"

how do i default the from time to 00:00:00.000 aka midnight on that day and to time to 23:59:59:999 on that day

idea is to use these 2 time as a "data filter", to catch all payload within these 2 timestamps

expected time to set properly but system differ to using current time while maintaining changed dates

Comment: Format this part of the string  - T15:30:42.000Z to T00:00:00.000Z  and run it back into new Date().toISOString()

Comment: Do you really need the time? Does the datepicker allow you to specify the time? Where is the 15:30 coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;

const DateRangeSelector = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(
    new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10) + 'T00:00:00.000Z'
  );
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(
    new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10) + 'T23:59:59:999Z'
  );
  const onDateChange = (e) => {
    
    e.target.name === 'start' ?
      setStartDate(e.target.value + 'T00:00:00.000Z') :
      setEndDate(e.target.value + 'T23:59:59:999Z');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      Start:&nbsp;
      <input
        name="start"
        type="date"
        value={startDate.slice(0, 10)}
        max={endDate}
        onChange={onDateChange}
      />
      End:&nbsp;
      <input
        name="end"
        type="date"
        value={endDate.slice(0, 10)}
        min={startDate}
        onChange={onDateChange}
      />
      <br />
      StartDate:&nbsp;{startDate} <br />
      EndDate:&nbsp;{endDate}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( <
  DateRangeSelector / >
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```